# Android Show autocomplete values within a HashMap

Tags: android

```
public class Select_outlet_sales extends Activity {

    private AutoCompleteTextView select_outlet;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>  > ar=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String> >();
    HashMap<String, String> x=new HashMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_outlet_sales);
        select_outlet = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.select_outlet);
        select_outlet.setTextIsSelectable(true);

        getValues();

        ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ar);
        select_outlet.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void getValues() {
        x.put("id"," aaaaa");
        ar.add(x);
    }
}
```

Here I used the above code to show data stored in a `Hashmap` but i want to display only the value of id. But when i try that it shows the entire hash map.Can you help me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `ar` but do something like this

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
        {
            strings.add(x.get("id"));
        }

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,strings);
         select_outlet.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: In this method  how i get the clicked value related to the id

Comment: Acttuly i need to get the position of  arraylist when the item is clicked so  I can get the oter values of the hashmap

Comment: U have to search the list by using that string value.

Answer (score 0):

That's because inside ArrayAdapter created list of HashMaps. You should translate your HashMap into `ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>` for example and override method getView of ArrayAdapter.

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pair<String, String>>{

        public MyAdapter (Context context, List<Pair<String, String>> data) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if(view == null) {
                view = new TextView(getContext());
            }
            ((TextView)view).setText(getItem(position).second);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this work but when i click the autocomplte value  it shows the hashmap entire value instead of "aaaaaa"

Comment: What is entire value? I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
 select_outlet.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)parent.getItemAtPosition
                    (position);
            Iterator<String> iterator = hashMap.keySet().iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) iterator.next();
                String value = (String)hashMap.get(key);
                select_outlet.setText(value);
            }

        }
    });
```

This will show only "aaaaa"in AutoComplete textbox.